# Firebase tests runtime - iOS UI Tests run twice longer than Android tests

Tags: android, ios, firebase, testing

Could you please suggest, why in Firebase tests for Android run 2,5 hours and tests for iOS with the same functionality and same amount of tests run 5-6 Hours?

We have optimized tests code for iOS. Nothing helps to reduce the runtime in Firebase.

Comment: Maybe iOS test generally run slower, maybe your tests have a problem, maybe the iOS queue for firebase is clogged. Hard to say. We don't even know how long your tests need if run locally.

Comment: Firebase was written for the Android and integrates nicely in the Android environment.  We see similar troubles with Firebase not working nearly as optimally on an iOS device.  It just doesn't do things the "apple way".

Comment: This question is hard to answer because we don't know what hardware you are testing, the kinds of tests these are and also do not know the skills of the programmer. If you can provide more information and a snippet of your android code and the comparative Swift code, we may be able to spot some differences. And @HalR Firebase wasn't just written 'for the android' lol! It does lot's of things the Apple way (Swift), and the Java way, and the Android way and the C++ way and... It's a cross platform API so it runs on lots of platforms.